# defining recursively a function with multiple if conditions

Tags: programming, variable-definitions, recursion

I am trying to recursively define a function which satisfies the following system of equations and which depends on two parameters $n$ and $l$,

$$
\begin{align}
A(x, n, l) &= F[ A(x,n-1,l)  ]\\
A(x, n, l) &= x^l \mbox{  if } l = n \\
A(x, n, l) &= 0 \mbox{ if }  l < n \\
\end{align}
$$

In order to do this I used the following code (here I make the expression for $F$ explicit):

```
A[x_, n_, l_]:=
  Boole[n > l]((1 - x)/(1 + x^l) * (Sum[A[x, n-1-i, l] * x^i, {i,0,l-1}])
  + x^l/(1 + x^l)) + Boole[n == l] * x ^ l
```

The function defined in this way, $A(x, n, l)\;$, gives the probability that tossing a coin $n$ times gives exactly one run of $l$ consecutive $1$s, where $x$ is the probability getting $1$ on single toss and $(1-x)$ is the probability getting $0$ on single toss.

When I try to plot one of these functions, for instance,

```
Plot[A[x, 7, 7], {x, 0, 1}]
```

I encounter the following error:

> RecursionLimit::reclim: Recursion depth of 256 exceeded.

Is my code wrong? Is there an other way to recursively define a function, taking into account the fact that the third condition must be satisfied for *all* the values $l<n$, where $l$ and $n$ are not specified at the moment of the definition.

Comment: You can use `NestWhile` to implement recursive functions.

Comment: You need to define a starting value for `A[x,0,l]`, and memoize your function, I think.

Comment: Your code doesn't seem to match your definition. For instance f depends on x not on `A[x,n-1,l]` as you write initially. Could you write out what `F[input_]` is supposed to be?

Comment: The reason your code gives a recursion error is because `Boole[condition] * expr` causes `expr` to be evaluated whether condition is `True` **or** `False`. So when you evaluate `A[x,7,7]` *Mathematica* will evaluate the `Sum`. The first term of the `Sum` is `A[x,6,7]`, and of course evaluating that leads to a `Sum` whose first term is `A[x,5,7]` and so on.

Answer (score 5):

I am sorry, but have hard time understanding your code with the use of Bool.

This does the same thing as you have, using `Piecewise` which is easier to understand

Also, hard to read `l` as variable name, it looks like `1`. It is not a good idea to use `l` for variable. Also, not good idea to user UpperCase `A`. Changed to `f`.

```
f[x_, n_, r_] :=
 Piecewise[{
   {(1 - x)/(1 + x^r)*(Sum[f[x,n-1-i,r]*x^i,{i, 0, r - 1}])+x^r/(1 + x^r),n>r},
   {x^r, n == r},
   {0, True}
   }]

Plot[f[x, 7, 7], {x, 0, 1}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thank you. This was really usefull!

Although I would like to understand why my example doesn't work...

Comment: Lorenzo, did you notice that `f[x,n,0]` is always $1/2$ for positive $n$? (Its other values tend to be incorrect, too, which becomes obvious when you plot them.) I think the problem is not with Nasser's solution, but with your recurrence: it does not correctly give the probability you are hoping to compute.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an alternate way of structuring the definition of your function that avoids the use of `If` completely by employing a combination of conditional expression evaluation and argument pattern matching:

```
j[x_, n_, l_] := 0 /; l < n
j[x_, l_, l_] := x^l
j[x_, n_, l_] := (1-x)/(1 + x^l)*(Sum[j[x, n-1-i,l]*x^i, {i,0,l-1}]) + x^l/(1+x^l)
```

And plotted:

```
Plot[j[x, 7, 7], {x, 0, 1}]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: This example works only for l=n, I have just tried...

Comment: @Lorenzo, the third condition in your question uses the condition `l < n` when it should be `n < l`. image_doctor has reproduced that error in the first definition for `j`.

Comment: @Lorenzo As far as I can tell there is no terminating condition in your definition of `A` when `l > n` as `n` is being decremented and will never equal or exceed `l`.